# Error installing Rails on Macbook Air OS 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have been trying to install rails on my Macbook Air running OSX 10.9, but I keep running into errors.

When I type

> $ gem -v

I get

> 2.0.3

and

> $ rails -v

yields

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>   
>  $ sudo gem install rails
>   
>  You can then rerun your "rails" command.

When I type

> $ gem install rails

I get

> Fetching: i18n-0.6.9.gem (100%)
>   
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>   
> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

So I type

> $ sudo gem install rails

I put in my password and I get

> Fetching: i18n-0.6.9.gem (100%)
>   
> Successfully installed i18n-0.6.9
>   
> Fetching: multi_json-1.8.2.gem (100%)
>   
> Successfully installed multi_json-1.8.2
>   
> Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.38.gem (100%)
>   
> Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.38
>   
> Fetching: minitest-4.7.5.gem (100%)
>   
> Successfully installed minitest-4.7.5
>   
> Fetching: atomic-1.1.14.gem (100%)
>   
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   
> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>   
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

and then I don't know what to do...

Comment: I suggest you install and use a ruby version manager, such as RVM, RBenv, or chruby, you'll run into less problems that with the bundled ruby in mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps in the blog post below and I finally got rails working on my 2012 MacBook Air running Maverick(10.9.4).

http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/

Though probably overkill, I reloaded Terminal after I entered each line.

Now when I type:

```
$gem -v
```

I get

```
2.0.3
```

and if I type

```
$ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

And finally, when I type

```
$rails -v
```

I get

```
Rails 4.1.4
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem on my MacBook Pro.  You'll want to use a ruby version manager.

The reason a ruby manager will solve this problem is because the tool is installed into a path that is write-accessible to you — thus you will not get `permission denied` errors when installing.

1. If you haven't already, you'll need to install `homebrew`: http://brew.sh/
2. then install either:

   ```
   brew install rbenv.
   ```

   or

   ```
   brew install rvm
   ```

Personally, I use `rbenv`, but either works well under OS X.

After you have either `rvm` or `rbenv` installed and working, install your gem as usual.

Comment: For yet another option, there's chruby. I use it, along with ruby-install. Both are available from homebrew (`brew install ruby-install chruby`). I previously used rvm and rbenv, and it's ultimately a matter of preference.

Comment: Okay, I installed brew and rbenv. But I still get the same errors when I try `$ gem install rails`

Comment: Make sure you open a new terminal window, or if you're using `zsh`, use `. ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I think I'm missing something here, I have rbenv installed, is rbenv suppose to install rails now?  `$ gem install rails` still yields `Rails is not currently installed on this system.` I am using Terminal.  I have ruby 2.0.3 installed. Rbenv installed,

Comment: No, rbenv only manages your ruby versions.  You'll want to install ruby first and then `gem install rails`.  To install the latest ruby with rbenv, you'll want to `brew install ruby_build` and then run `rbenv install 2.1.0`

Comment: Also, don't forget to open a new terminal window or reload your shell environment after you get `rvm` or `rbenv` working properly.